# Java- Main method cannot be found in class

Tags: java, swing, program-entry-point

I knows that this subject has been breached a few times, but I ran into an error when fixing it the way that it was said to be fixed in the others ones.

```
public static class FlowAp extends JFrame{
    String one = "One";
    String two = "Two";
    String three = "Three";
    String four = "Four";
    String five = "Five";

public static void main(String argv[]){
    FlowAp fa=new FlowAp();
    //Change from BorderLayout default
    fa.getContentPane().setLayout(new FlowLayout());
    fa.setSize(200,200);
    fa.setVisible(true);
}
FlowAp(){

    JButton one = new JButton("One");
    getContentPane().add(one);
    JButton two = new JButton("Two");
    getContentPane().add(two);
    JButton three = new JButton("Three");
    getContentPane().add(three);
    JButton four = new JButton("four");
    getContentPane().add(four);
    JButton five = new JButton("five");
    getContentPane().add(five);

}
}
```

When I actually put in the parenthesis where they look as though they should be, another error shows up with the flowap."invalid method declaration"

Comment: *Where* is the invalid method declaration, exactly? And is this a nested class inside another? Please give *all* the details of the errors you're seeing.

Comment: How do you try to start the program?

Comment: Question title does not seem to match body.

Comment: If you actually had a decent compiler, you'd get the following error - "Illegal modifier for the class FlowAp; only public, abstract & final are permitted"

Comment: a) It says the erro on "FlowAp fa=new FlowAp();  b) That is the start of the program.      c) That is the error, I simply stated that the fix that the others gave in another thread wouldn't work because of a different error.       d) I'm using NetBeans 7.0.1

Answer (score 2):

The modifier "static" for your class is not allowed in your case - remove it and it will work. If you want to access your variables you have to make them static so that you can reference them from the main method.

Comment: I didn't think so, but it was saying that there was no way that this would work without the static. It was giving a separate error message, about how you cannot reference a non-static variable in a static context.

Comment: Then you ought to make your variables static, not your class

Answer (score 2):

Try removing "static":

```
public class FlowAp extends JFrame{
```

Comment: When I remove the static from class, it states that I cannot reference a non-static variable in a static context.

Answer (score 2):

please [there](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/index.html) are basic stuff, there are lots of mistakes and I can't comment something, then

[image]

from code

```
import java.awt.FlowLayout;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

public class FlowAp extends JFrame {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private String one = "One";
    private String two = "Two";
    private String three = "Three";
    private String four = "Four";
    private String five = "Five";

    public FlowAp() {
        JButton oneButton = new JButton(one);
        JButton twoButton = new JButton(two);
        JButton threeButton = new JButton(three);
        JButton fourButton = new JButton(four);
        JButton fiveButton = new JButton(five);

        setTitle("FlowAp");
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setLayout(new FlowLayout());
        add(oneButton);
        add(twoButton);
        add(threeButton);
        add(fourButton);
        add(fiveButton);
        setLocation(100, 100);
        pack();
        setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String argv[]) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                FlowAp fa = new FlowAp();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Should be:

```
public static void main(String[] argv){
```

Post the error which occurs when you write this.

Note:
- A class cannot be static.

Comment: Doesn't make any difference. The `[]`s are generally preferred your way around, but the C-compatibility way works.

Comment: In java it doesn't really matter where [] are String[] blah is the same as String blah[];